# Java check instance of an object when it's obj is unknown

Tags: java

I'm new to Java with a decent background in python. I'm looking for a magic sauce in Java which is equivalent to `isinstance()` in python. I know we can do something like

```
if (cls.isInstance(obj)){  ... }
```

But I don't even know which `cls` it would be so I need something to tell me what instance is `obj` is. I can't check for hundreds of classes.
Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

I'm dealing with some exception which is wrapped in few other custom exceptions. My primary goal was to catch the exception for which I need to know what instance it is.

Comment: try obj.getClass()

Comment: The equivalent to Python's `isinstance(obj, cls)` is `(obj instanceof cls)`. And even in Python you need to know what class you're asking about. How would you use `isinstance` in Python if you didn't know what `cls` you were asking about?

Comment: Thanks for the downvote but may I know why ?

Comment: I don't quite get what exactly you are trying to archieve. If you have no idea what class it even could be what exactly is your end goal here?

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Please look at the edits

Answer (score 1):

you can check the class instance by `instanceof` keyword in java. It returns true or false.

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
if(obj instanceof MyClass) {
   //Do what you want
}
```

If you want to check exceptions which exception it is then in java every Exception is child of `Exception` class. you will check for any number of classes in which exception may be wrapped. at the end you will catch in `Exception` type. Now every exception will be catch.

```
try{

} catch(CustommException1 e) {

} catch(CustomException2 e) {

} catch(Exception e) {

}
```

Comment: SO is weird @KhalidShah

Comment: @KhalidShah didn't downvote, but one reason could be: the OP stated that his situation is: Object obj; // type is unknown. on what type would you check instanceof?

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Yeah exactly . :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the full name of the class of obj by using

```
obj.getClass().getName()
```

If you don't like package names, you can also do

```
obj.getClass().getSimpleName()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try instanceof operator... 
for example:

```
`   class Simple1{  
         public static void main(String args[]){  
         Simple1 s=new Simple1();  
         System.out.println(s instanceof Simple1);//true  
     }  
  }  `
```

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions have inheritance too. That means you don't have to know its exact class to catch it.

So if you want to catch *every* exception, you do

```
try {
     // the code that throws the exception
} catch (Exception e) {
     // handling the exception
}
```

If you are really desparate you can replace the `Exception` above with `Throwable`, to catch even more stuff, but in most cases, that would be a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get a specific *custom class* by using `instanceof` or `.getClass()` in an `Object`. It would give you a type of `LinkedHashMap`.

To know the specific *instance* of the `Object`, the only way is checking its `Keys`, or trying to cast it.

There isn't a "magic sauce" that gives you what type of a *custom class* is an `Object`.